# PLS 00302 : component DATA_TYPE must de declared in function

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have to following oracle function, build_select,  which create a select request.  The return value is in the following format:

```
select col1 ||'|'||col2 ||'|'||col3 from table;
```

Below is the build_select function:

```
create or replace FUNCTION build_select (
  p_table_name   IN VARCHAR2
)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
    l_ret   VARCHAR2 (32767);
BEGIN
    FOR eachcol IN (  SELECT column_name, data_type
                           , LEAD (column_name), LEAD (data_type)
                                 OVER (
                                     PARTITION BY table_name ORDER BY column_id
                                 )
                                 next_column
                        FROM all_tab_cols
                       WHERE table_name = p_table_name
                    ORDER BY column_id)
    LOOP
      IF eachcol.data_type = 'CLOB' THEN
        l_ret   := l_ret || dbms_lob.substr( eachcol.column_name, 3000, 1 ) || CASE WHEN eachcol.next_column IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE ' ||''|''||' END;
      ELSE 
        l_ret   := l_ret || eachcol.column_name || CASE WHEN eachcol.next_column IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE ' ||''|''||' END;
      END IF;
    END LOOP;

    IF l_ret IS NULL
    THEN
        raise_application_error (-20001, 'table ' || p_table_name || ' not found');
    END IF;

    l_ret   := 'select ' || l_ret || ' from ' || p_table_name || ';';

    RETURN l_ret;
END build_select;
```

What I want to do is to test if the data type of the column is CLOB and if so then return it as

```
dbms_lob.substr( eachcol.column_name, 3000, 1 )
```

I have added the if else condition in the loop part.  But I am getting the error :

```
PLS 00302 : component DATA_TYPE must de declared.
```

Any help pls?

I need to do so cause when I am doing a spool of the returned select, it is not returning all the columns cause of the CLOB data type.

Comment: The code you posted has an error: `LEAD (column_name)` missing window specification. This does not match your error description. Fix the posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your function should be this:

```
create or replace FUNCTION build_select (
  p_table_name   IN VARCHAR2
)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
    l_ret   VARCHAR2 (32767);
BEGIN
    FOR eachcol IN (  SELECT column_name, data_type
                        FROM all_tab_cols
                       WHERE table_name = p_table_name
                    ORDER BY column_id)
    LOOP
      IF eachcol.data_type = 'CLOB' THEN
        l_ret   := l_ret || 'dbms_lob.substr( '||eachcol.column_name||', 3000, 1 ),';
      ELSE 
        l_ret   := l_ret || eachcol.column_name||',';
      END IF;
    END LOOP;

    IF l_ret IS NULL
    THEN
        raise_application_error (-20001, 'table ' || p_table_name || ' not found');
    END IF;

    l_ret   := 'select ' || regexp_replace(l_ret, ',$', NULL) || ' from ' || p_table_name || ';';

    RETURN l_ret;
END build_select;
```

Note, `ALL_TAB_COLS` selects also system-generated hidden columns and invisible columns which could be a problem. Query `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` if you like to filter them.